# Moving files inside multiple directories to the root directroy of the folder structure

Tags: command-line, files, mv

In this directory listing below I'm trying to move all 'example*.file' into the 'test' directory.

I've tried doing something like `mv * ./test/`  but that only moves the folders and not just the files, I've looked in mv --help and couldn't find an option to ignore the folders. I've also tried cp without -r but it didn't work. and is there a way to touch files to multiple directories from the root directory, for example in the tree below, you'd be inside test then do touch  to create files in all directories inside of it rather than just the root directory you are in.

```
$ tree ./test/
./test/
├── 1
│   └── example.file
├── 10
│   └── example (14th copy).file
├── 11
│   └── example (12th copy).file
├── 12
│   └── example (7th copy).file
├── 13
│   └── example (17th copy).file
├── 14
│   └── example (16th copy).file
├── 15
│   ├── example (14th copy).file
│   └── example (15th copy).file
├── 16
│   ├── example (12th copy).file
│   └── example (13th copy).file
├── 17
│   └── example (11th copy).file
├── 18
│   └── example (10th copy).file
├── 19
│   └── example (9th copy).file
├── 2
│   └── example (3rd copy).file
├── 20
│   └── example (8th copy).file
├── 3
│   └── example (5th copy).file
├── 4
│   └── example (4th copy).file
├── 5
│   └── example (8th copy).file
├── 6
│   └── example (11th copy).file
├── 7
│   └── example (13th copy).file
├── 8
│   └── example (another copy).file
└── 9
    └── example (copy).file

20 directories, 22 files
```

Comment: The `*` glob only matches items in the current directory - you'd need something like `mv ./test/*/example*.file ./test/` to make `*` match all the *directories* directly under `./test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filenames are unique, and since the filenames contain funny characters `()`, `find` and `xargs` are the way to go, and the `man` pages to read.

```
find test -type f -print0 |\
  echo xargs -0 -r mv --target-directory=test
```

Remove the `echo` when you're happy with the results, and want to actually do the `mv`